Battery isnt shown and charged as well
My battery isnt shown, even in settings under power option any information of battery is missing.
plus i am dealing with laptop not charging. for few second it get charged then goes off. I try to power on after unplugging charger but it wont turn on.
So i quickly plug in charge while chargin indicator blinks and power on then it turn on but chargin indicator goes off and as soon as i plugged out charger laptop turns off.
user@user:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 AM +0530 (1729919206 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    percentage:          0% (should be ignored)
    icon-name:          '(null)'

rudy@rudy:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble



Sorry I put this as an answer because I can't comment yet
I suspect that the battery being dead, Ubuntu cannot show battery status.
The output you are getting is normally for OS running on Desktop, with no battery
However, as suggested in these answers, you may try :

Start power indicator service

$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown


Make sure it's installed (or trying to reinstall)

$ sudo apt-get install indicator-power

# or
$ sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
$ sudo apt-get install indicator-power


If you have gnome, you may try setting :

$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true


Got no such key active on running
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true


At last i changed battery , now since battery is changed its working fine. So found out that it was damaged
